# Resources to make a racing wheel driver for linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, proprietary-drivers

As some of you might know, not all racing wheel is supported on linux. So, I thought I should make driver for thrustmaster T128. Any good resources out there to learn to make a racing wheel driver for linux. I've only heard of "Linux device drivers" by O'Riely. If I were to read all of it will it be enough to make a racing wheel driver for linux?

Comment: That's impossible to know, because we don't know your programming skills nor how that wheel works.

Comment: I've been programming for a while now might aswell jump to the deep end. So, the book "Linux device drivers" isn't enough to make a racing wheel driver. Then how are racing wheel driver made in linux. Are they officialy made by people from that company ? e.g fanatec wheels driver are made by people from that company

Comment: Again, I said "impossible to tell", and I meant that. You're not really giving us any additional information.

Comment: That's quite the project to begin with, but you can look at [this](https://github.com/berarma/oversteer) to see how much you could get without writing a driver. Since Logitech wheels are better supported, it is a good idea to see how those work. But without support from the vendor, it's not going to be easy.

Comment: I suggest you read the existing kernel code & use that as a base.

Comment: yeah, I've heard of oversteer for linux. Doesn't work with my wheel which is Thrustmaster T128.